# How do I receive elements into an array using scanf?

Tags: arrays, c, function, scanf

I'm learning C programming and I've encountered a problem using `scanf` for initializing values into the array. [In this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGHfJ.jpg), `10`, `32` and `20` were input as values for the array; `20` should be in `grades[2]` but its value is `0`.

Why doesn't the program register the last value that is input?

That is the relevant code.

I'll appreciate any help in understanding what went wrong with the program.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 50
#define MaximalSTD 10

int main() {
    printf("Please enter the grades of the examinees");
    printf(" followed by the expected mean\n");
    double grades[N], ReqMean; 
    int numgrade = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%lf", &grades[i]) == 1) {
            numgrade++;
        } else
            break;
    }
    ReqMean = grades[numgrade - 1];
    printf("numgrade: %d\nReqMean: %d\n", numgrade, ReqMean);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your "scanf" looks reasonable to me, but just to be sure, instead of scanf-ing into an array element directly, scanf into a local variable "temp" and then assign temp to "grades[i]".

Comment: What's the value of `N`?  It's good that you check the return value from `scanf()`, but it is best to check that you got the correct number of values — `if (scanf("%lf", &grades[i]) == 1)`.  That's because `scanf()` can also return `EOF` which is also not zero, and would lead to your code looping unnecessarily.  The counter on the loop prevents too much damage, but it is best to be precise.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mark, I have tried your method, but none of the values intialized . [link](https://imgur.com/a/JX9zacR)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi Jonathan, The value of N is 50 (it is written above as #define N 50) I've tried"  if (scanf("%lf", &grades[i]) == 1)" and I did get the correct number of values (can be seen in  "numgrade") but the third value is still 0. (note that I have to write a non valid character for the program to actually run)    [link](https://imgur.com/a/Wlse4pn)

Comment: We're gonna need to see the example data.  It would be a good idea to read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  What you had first was about right — but adding all the code was not actually an provement.

Comment: That edit is excellent — an MCVE indeed!  Note that better modern compilers will report mismatches between the conversion specifier in a format string and the variable type passed.  You should add warning options to your compiler command line to get more extensive warnings — if you use GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` as a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("numgrade: %d\nReqMean: %d\n" , numgrade,ReqMean);
```

You are using the wrong format specifier for a double value **(ReqMean in this case)**.
Try Instead.

```
printf("numgrade: %d\nReqMean: %lf\n" , numgrade,ReqMean);
```

Comment: This has answered my question and fixed the issue, thank you.